# creating google maps marker in a for loop

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to declare google maps marker in a for loop. Here is my code:

```
public void latlong() throws JSONException {

    JSONArray jsonArrayData = jsonData.getJSONArray("rows");

    for (int i = 0; i <  jsonArrayData.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject c = jsonArrayData.getJSONObject(i);

        JSONObject tmpObject = c.getJSONObject("value");
        String latString = tmpObject.getString("latitude");
        String longString = tmpObject.getString("longitude");

        double lat = Double.parseDouble(latString);
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(longString);

        System.out.println("lat: " + lat + " // long: " + lng);

       MarkerOptions place = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat ,lng)).title("Hello Maps");
       googleMap.addMarker(place);

    }
}
```

I don't know why I'm getting a java.lang.NullPointerException.
Thanks for any help!

Logcat:

```
02-12 01:19:02.363    9648-9648/emama.stadtrundgang E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: emama.stadtrundgang, PID: 9648
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)' on a null object reference
            at emama.stadtrundgang.MapFragment.latlong(MapFragment.java:118)
            at emama.stadtrundgang.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:40)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:249)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your map does not seem to have been initialized. In order to have your map initialized, you need to call yourFragment.getMapAsync() in your onCreate() method and then you'll get a callback like this:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10, 10))
        .title("Hello world"));
}
```

If your markers depend on a async call to a json resource, you can set a flag in your activity like this:

boolean isMapReady = false;
boolean isDataLoaded = false;

and then in both onMapReady() and latlong() you can check the flag and call for example a addMarkers() method. See example below:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    isMapReady = true;
    if(isDataLoaded)
        addMarkers(map, jsonData);
}

public void latLong() {
    data = YOUR_DATA;
    isDataLoaded = true;

    if(isMapReady)
        addMarkers(map, jsonData);
}
```

Comment: I'm creating the google map on a fragment. So I need to call yourFragment.getMapAsync() in my onCreatView method?

Comment: You can call that in your activity by retrieving the fragment and calling mapFragment.getMapAsync() or from the inside of your fragment. Example here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Comment: sorry for my stupidness but when I want to call "getMapAsync(this)" in the Fragments onCreateView method it's telling me that this method cannot be resolved.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Are you creating your map fragment inside a fragment or inside your activity?

Comment: I'm creating my map inside a fragment and I use a mapView instead of an mapFragment in my xml file. When I call the method getMapAsync() with mMapView (mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView)) and I don't call mMapView.getMap() the map wouldn't appear.

Comment: Read this, everything is explained: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you try to place the markers on the map, your map hasnt been loaded/initialized yet

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)' on a null object referenc